# How to define a table so it shows on every page, but doesn't interfere with editing?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I need a table in Word 2007, which needs to be on every page of the document. It is actually not a table per se, but a frame with three columns. The problem is it cannot interfere with editing, so I'm trying to avoid just inserting a lot of tables, and for now am using a *made up table*, made of lines, which I've putted in header field over the entire page.

Is there a better way to do it then this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question then you should insert a table in the header.

[image]

After you select how many columns and rows to display then you can type any text in it.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering :) The problem is that table needs to go on the whole page, from top to bottom. It is actually a technical calculation standard design for a page. In the middle you put your calculations, in the right your results and in the left your references. So the outer lines of the table would have to fit just within the margins.

Comment: I understand now.
One solution I can think of now is to insert three frames and add them to Quick Parts. (you can resize them to fit the margins: insert 1st frame then drag&drop the frame right next to it, holding the Shift+CTRL keys until you see a dotted line to properly overlap it. Then do the same for the 3rd frame).

Comment: Frames don't interfere with editing... Except for the fact you have the frames added in the Quick Parts to easily insert them when you need (even in headers), I cannot think of any other easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make an image of the 'table' you want to fill the page with. 
Use that image as a background for the page.

If you want to use the columns in the 'table' use the columns function in Word and line them up like they should.